# Magento Edit Order Invoice PDF - Options on Single Line

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, invoice, pdf

I want to edit the code inside **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/items/Invoice/Default.php**

so each product option has the format
Label - Value, instead of taking up multiple lines; as this creates a 2 page pdf when the contained information can be displayed on a single page.

Any advice someone can offer would be greatly appreciated, as it's one of the last issues I have to complete before I'm finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $lines[][] = array(
                        'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                        'font' => 'italic',
                        'feed' => 35
                    );

                    if ($option['value']) {
                        if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                            $_printValue = $option['print_value'];
                        } else {
                            $_printValue = strip_tags($option['value']);
                        }
                        $values = explode(', ', $_printValue);
                        foreach ($values as $value) {
                            $lines[][] = array(
                                'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 30, true, true),
                                'feed' => 40
                            );
                        }
                    }
```

replace with

```
$lines[][] = array(
                    'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($option['label'].':'.$option['value']), 40, true, true),
                    'font' => 'italic',
                    'feed' => 35
                );
```